# Ввести 3 массива

Tags: java, массивы

Нужно ввести 3 массива на java,Массивы 1)Имена студентов,2)Предметы, 3)Содержат имена+предметы и ещё оценки. Нужно чтоб потом выводились данные сколько у каждого студента предметов, по скольким он неуд и самого плохого студента. Всё вводиться с клавиатуры. Не мог найти как вводить данные в массив. Хотя бы как вводить данные и чтоб он выводились, кто мог бы подсказать?

Comment: С нуля, без наработок вам здесь помогать не будут. Возникнут конкретные проблемы, обращайтесь.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, конечно, несложный, но раз надо - вот ответ:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Объявляем Scanner - он принимает данные с клавиатуры
    System.out.println("Enter array length: ");
    int size = input.nextInt(); // Читаем с клавиатуры размер массива и записываем в size
    int array[] = new int[size]; // Создаём массив int размером в size
    System.out.println("Insert array elements:");
    // Пройдёмся по всему массиву, заполняя его
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = input.nextInt(); // Заполняем массив элементами, введёнными с клавиатуры
    }
}
```

P.S. Не забудьте подключить `Scanner`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: Ох, зря невежество и нежелание учиться поощрается :)

Comment: @Komdosh, да я в основном ради своего вопроса сейчас тут сижу =)